# Error: Can't Access CiviCRM Extensions

Tags: extension

Following upgrade to 4.7.14 we are seeing two errors in lightboxes when opening Civi:

> Unable to download extension from
>   https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=4.7.14|cms=Drupal/single. Error
>   Message: SSL connect error
>
> The CiviCRM public extensions directory at
>   https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=4.7.14|cms=Drupal could not be
>   contacted - please check your webserver can make external HTTP
>   requests or contact CiviCRM team on CiviCRM forum.

I have used wget on the server to check that it can access the address, which it can, and the SSL certificate for civicrm.org seems predictably valid! Has anyone else seen this error?

Comment: For one thing, that link doesn't go anywhere nice. I'm wondering why there is a pipe in the URL. Can you tell us what method you used to download the extension? From CiviCRM.org directly, from within your CiviCRM admin panel by clicking add extension, from drush or some other way?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, can you share what extension you are trying to add?

Comment: I have the same problem with Wordpress and 4.7.14. I am not trying to do anything special at all (I am not trying to do anything with extensions, for example)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else this might help - I ran a Cleanup Caches via /civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1

and the site started working fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved itself / cleared without further action - guess it was a server or connectivity issue.

Comment: My guess is that it was a caching issue. Glad it's working out now!