# Extension Download Errors

Tags: extension, 4.7.14

I'm looking for help troubleshooting "Extensions Download" errors. Like [Error: Can't Access CiviCRM Extensions](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/error-cant-access-civicrm-extensions), I've recently been getting lots of "Unable to download extension from ..." lightbox errors. My host confirmed there aren't any SSL protocol errors logged on our end, and suggested the issues are probably with civicrm.org's certificate(s) and/or the encoding of the xml files.

The System Status page reads:

> Extension Download Error: The CiviCRM public extensions directory at https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=4.7.14|cms=Drupal could not be contacted - please check your webserver can make external HTTP requests or contact CiviCRM team on CiviCRM forum.

I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.14 with Drupal 7.52, and can usually troubleshoot issues, but I'm new to CiviCRM and can't think of anything I can do about this. Any suggestions?

[image: CiviCRM Drupal Extensions Error Message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to suppress this error, please add the following lines at the end of your civicrm.settings.php file and clear the cache.

```
global $civicrm_setting;    
$civicrm_setting['Extension Preferences']['ext_repo_url'] = false;
```

Please check civicrm extension documentation on the below link:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extensions#Extensions-Disableautomaticinstallationsofextension

Comment: Hi, this removes using the external fetching, so you loose the feature to be able to see and download extensions. It's a good way to hide the problem. but it doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 3):

two reasons I can think of:
- civicrm website was overloaded or down for a short maintenance operation
- your server or network connection prevents your site to connect to civicrm

if it's the former, wait a bit an retry, everything should be back to normal

to test if it's the later, try to connect to the site from the command line (if you have ssh access to your server) and run curl https://civicrm.org. if you have an error message, it should point you to the right direction

(we did change something about the TLS/SSL protocol accepted but don't recall if it was the main site or not). In any case, it would probably mean you have very old software on your server and you should upgrade your OS

Comment: Your "curl https://civicrm.org" test confirmed it's the latter ("unknown SSL protocol error"). I've checked with my host, but they didn't find anything wrong with the cipher and couldn't pin-point the source of the error. So, I'm following @rajesh 's suggestion to turn off the external repo checks (for now).

Answer (score 1):

Go into Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs or `<site_root>civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1` and change "Verify SSL Certs" to "No". When you are done adding extensions you can turn it back to "yes".